# QR decomposition and matrix dimensions

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

How does the time for `qr` depend on matrix dimensions $m$ and $n$ of $A$ ($A \in \mathbb R^{m×n}$? I tried to test the computational time in MATLAB using `tic` and `toc`. I got the following:

[image]

So `qr` works faster if $m<n$. What's the reason for this?

EDIT: I'm actually testing the backslash operator for rectangular matrices as well, and got the similar result. MATLAB Documentation says that if $A$ is non-square, backslash $QR$ solver. Does the time for backslash depend on matrix dimensions $m$ and $n$ of $A$ as well?

Comment: What are the actual values for $n$ and $m$? Maybe one is just a larger problem than the other?

Comment: @them, red line is for a 700 x 500 matrix, and the blue line is for a 500 x 700 matrix ... So you're saying that it shouldn't depend on m and n?

Comment: Just tried to illuminate the simple explanation first. Another possibility,  to compute QR factorization the operations are performed on the columns. Therefore in the the m>n case, we have arithmetic operations  on vectors of  larger dimensions so it takes longer (you can perhaps try to look into the source of `Matlab` function to verify this).

Comment: I suggest that you implement a QR factorization routine yourself. You can use Gram-Schmidt, Householder reflectors or Givens rotations. It does not have to optimal. Once you have a working code, you will find it easy to modify it it to count the number of flops. You will then be able to verify any hypothesis that you might have. Failing that, you could gather data for different $m$ and $n$ and fit a polynomial surface to the data. Of course you will have to do several runs to eliminate the noise you have seen.